# Prompt for user yes or no input in Java

Tags: java, variables, loops

how to prompt user to loop the code yes to loop no to exit and wrong input print wrong input and go back to statement ie. "do you want to enter another name:"

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class loop {
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner kbd = new Scanner (System.in);
    String decision;
    boolean yn;
    while(true){

        System.out.println("please enter your name");
        String name = kbd.nextLine();

        System.out.println("you entered the name" + name );

        System.out.println("enter another name : yes or no");
        decision = kbd.nextLine();

        switch(decision){
        case "yes":
            yn = false;
            break;
        case "no": 
            yn = true;
            break;
        default : 
            System.out.println("please enter again ");
             return default;
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "to loop the code yes to loop..."?

Comment: IF USER ENTER YES THAN LOOP THE CODE FROM STARTING

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. If you don't use Java 7 you can't use switch-strings
2. Change `while (true)` with `while (yn)` so it will stop when he type "no", and change `boolean yn;` to `boolean yn = true;`
   And change the rules inside the cases too.

   ```
   case "yes":
        yn = false;
        break;
   case "no": 
        yn = true;
        break;
   ```

   `yn = true;` if `"yes"`;

   `yn = false;` if `"no"`;

   You could change the condition inside the while, with `while (!yn)` but is more intuitive to let `yn` `true` if yes; `false` if no.
3. `return default;` don't make much sense, if you want to let user repeat in case of error well.. you should do a new `while (true)` to repeat until he writes a correct one. I would write another method.

This is how you could do it

```
Scanner kbd = new Scanner (System.in);

String decision;

boolean yn = true;
while(yn)
{
    System.out.println("please enter your name");
    String name = kbd.nextLine();

    System.out.println("you entered the name" + name );

    System.out.println("enter another name : yes or no");
    decision = kbd.nextLine();


    switch(decision)
    {
        case "yes":
            yn = true;
            break;

        case "no":
            yn = false;
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("please enter again ");
            boolean repeat = true;

            while (repeat)
            {
                System.out.println("enter another name : yes or no");
                decision = kbd.nextLine();

                switch (decision)
                {
                    case "yes":
                        yn = true;
                        repeat = false;
                        break;

                    case "no":
                        yn = repeat = false;
                        break;
                    default:
                        repeat = true;
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Yes it will repeat `decision` code, but how it is created i think it is the only way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but you'd want `while(yn)`, not `while(true)`, which goes on forever. The `break` only breaks from the `switch` statement.

---

Alright, try this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public static void main(String args[]){
  Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

  boolean checking = true, valid = true;
  String[] names = new String[50];
  int i = 0;

  while(checking){
    System.out.println("Enter name...");
    me = s.nextLine();
    System.out.println("You entered " + me + ".");
    while(valid){
      System.out.println("Enter another? y/n");
      you = s.nextLine();
      if(you.equals("n")){
        valid = false;
        checking = false;
      }else if you.equals("y")){
        names[i] = you;
        i++;
        valid = false;
      }else{
        System.out.println("Sorry, try again (y/n)...");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i just need to loop the last decision statement eg 
if user input is yes than loop statement
if user input no than exit the statement 
if wrong input than loop the to re enter the input yes or no

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean input = true;
while(input){
//ask for name
//print message saying you entered xyz
//ask if user wants to enter other name
//if user enters no
//set input = false;
//else continue
}
```

try doing this

Comment: well it depends on how you want to implement it, if on wrong user input you want to exit, you can break the loop or else you can ask user to enter it again after reading his input if it is wrong

Answer (score 1):

Rather then break and while(true), you need to say `while(!yn)` as you set yn to false when the user input yes.

Comment: You have it currently with 'return default;' but I assume you just want to loop, so 'break;'

Comment: can u just code it for me because using break at default is getting me back to start of code enter name

Comment: Oops, that will cause you to input the name again. And you only want them to re-input 'yes' or 'no'.

Comment: yes thats what i m trying to say to get back to last statement if wrong input

Comment: Yeah, probably best to have two nested while loops: one for name/more names and the second one to check if user input yes or no. You exit the second one when the user has input yes or no, you exit the outer (first) one, when the user inputs no.

Answer (score 0):

I just created a small class *YesNoCommandPrompt* that does just that:

```
private String prompt;
private Supplier<T> yesAction;
private Supplier<T> noAction;

public YesNoCommandPrompt(String prompt, Supplier<T> yesAction, Supplier<T> noAction) {
    this.prompt = prompt;
    this.yesAction = yesAction;
    this.noAction = noAction;
}

// example usage
public static void main(String[] args) {
    YesNoCommandPrompt<String> prompt = new YesNoCommandPrompt<>(
            "Choose",
            () -> {return "yes";},
            () -> {return "no";});

    System.out.println(prompt.run());
}

public T run() {
    final String yesOption = "y";
    final String noOption = "n";
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        while (true) {
            System.out.print(prompt + " [" + yesOption + "/" + noOption + "]: ");
            String option = scanner.next();
            if (yesOption.equalsIgnoreCase(option)){
                return yesAction.get();
            }
            else if (noOption.equalsIgnoreCase(option)){
                return noAction.get();
            }
        }
    }
}
```